# php 7 deprecated constructor issue

Tags: php

I have php 7 and I am getting following error:

> [25-Feb-2017 01:29:12 UTC] PHP Deprecated:  Methods with the same name
>   as their class will not be constructors in a future version of PHP;
>   my_function has a deprecated constructor in /function.php on line 8

```
 class my_function{
       ...
      public function my_function(){}
      ...
 }
```

Before update, I never had any issue. I am not sure how to fix this.

Any suggestions? I am afraid it's going to mess up even more if I simply change the name. What's the issue here?

Thanks!

Comment: Replace `public function my_function()` with `public function __construct()`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In a very old version of PHP (PHP 4, to be precise), having a function name with the same name as the class was used as the constructor.

That is, if you were to call `new my_function()`, the method `my_function` inside the class would be called with any parameters.

Now, if you're using the `my_function` as a constructor, a drop-in replacement would be to rename it to `__construct`. That will work whenever an instance is initiated.

If, on the other hand, you just happen to have a function that shares a name with the class, and are not relying on it as a constructor, you should be able to ignore that warning altogether, as it's referencing a deprecated functionality that you're not using.

Edit: If it's the second scenario, make sure to also add a `public function __construct()`, if there's not one there already. Leaving it empty is fine, but just having it will make sure PHP doesn't inadvertently try to call `my_function` on instantiation, as the `__construct` will take precedence.

Example:

```
<?php

class Foo
{
    //DEPRECATED CONSTRUCTOR SYNTAX (Don't try this at home.)
    public function Foo()
    {
        echo "Foo named constructor\n"; 
    } 
}

$f = new Foo();
//Foo named constructor

class Bar
{
    public function __construct()
    {
        echo "Bar constructor\n";
    }

    public function Bar()
    {
        echo "Bar function\n";
    }
}

$b = new Bar();
//Bar constructor
$b->Bar();
//Bar function
```

Comment: Pretty good answer, perhaps you could offer a code example to be super-extra clear?

Comment: I would put a comment by public function Foo() that says // DO NOT DO THIS it is the old way which is now deprecated

Comment: Fair enough, just to make it explicit.

Answer (score 1):

It's just saying that convention is going away. Should be safe to rename it to `__construct`. This convention has been around since PHP 4.